# How to rotate an image in dart?

Tags: image-processing, dart

I'm trying to develop a simplistic 2D browser game with dart.
The player is drawn from a png-image represented by an ImageElement in dart.
I want the player-image  to turn towards the mousepointer, but cant find how to rotate an image in dart.
Any suggestions as to how this might be done?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I am drawing the player inside a canvas element. I tried it and it won't work, I suspect that is because of me drawing inside the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the StageXL library for this (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagexl). It's basically a recreation of the Flash APIs for Dart. It makes doing that sort of thing very easy, and it's often used to create Dart games.

Comment: I checked it out, but found it too big for my purpose. But I will keep it in mind for the next (bigger) game. I ended up with a simpler approach, but will give you the credit, because it's propably the best way to go to achieve what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using multiple images for the 8 general directions the player can move and set them accordingly.